# Why does my car have very poor acceleration?

Tags: engine, fuel-system, oil, turbocharger, peugeot-308

I have a 2009 Peugeot with the 308 cc THP engine. The car has poor acceleration.

Here are the codes:

- P2191
- P2261
- P2262
- P0243
- P0299

What do these mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this site](http://obdii.pro/en/model/peugeot) to look them up, here are what the codes mean;

- P2191 - System Too Lean at Higher Load Bank 1
- P2261 - Turbocharger/Supercharger Bypass Valve - Mechanical
- P2262 - Turbocharger/Supercharger Boost Pressure Not Detected - Mechanical
- P0243 - Turbocharger (TC) wastegate regulating valve A – circuit malfunction
- P0299 - Turbocharger (TC)/supercharger (SC) – low boost

It appears you have a major problem with your turbo charger system.

Comment: so , do you have any idea ?

Comment: That "major problem" could very well just be a leaking intake air hose, preventing the turbo from making boost.

Comment: @AminShahrokni , Charlie has suggested you have a major problem with your turbo system - now you need to check hoses for splits, check the actuators etc

Comment: @MadMarky some one said to me ; may be the engines timing chain is not work good , or out of nirmal position

Comment: @AminShahrokni None of those codes suggest anything about a timing chain, which is also a much less likely culprit. start with the turbo.